# Content from ScrollView -> Relative Layout is not shown

Tags: android, android-studio, scrollview, android-cardview

I want my content to be shown in this ScrollView. This ScrollView is in a CardView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#CCffffff"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textviewhead"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="..." />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textviewinfo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textviewhead"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    tools:text="..." />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textviewinfo2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textviewinfo"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    tools:text="..." />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I also tried it without LinearLayout but that didn't worked for me. In the preview of AndroidStudio the content is also displayed and you can also scroll. As soon as I try the whole thing in the emulator or on my mobile phone, you only see the white CardView.
I also tried to change "match_parent" to "wrap_content" but my mobile still shows nothing.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.
With kind regards

Jere

Comment: Is that fine, that your Cardview height and width is 0dp?

Comment: Yes that's ok, because it's in a grid. That's the reason why there's column weight.